# How to make Airplane Path Animation in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I want to show an animation of an Airplane from one point to another using flutter. [image]
I have achieved the path using `Path` in Flutter but don't have any idea about how I trace the path using an Airplane Icon. and at the end, I want a Location Marker to appear.

Comment: check `PathMetric` class

Comment: you could also use a lottie animation if that works for you